# How to send email in html form using express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new in nodejs,I am showing html file in home page(on localhost),in this file there is contact us form and i want to send email to user,How can i do this ? Here is my current code,Thanks in advance

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To send email you need one SMTP server and also you need to create one email service in node which will sent email.

OR

In other way you can use NPM module "nodemailer" to sent email
https://github.com/niftylettuce/email-templates

Comment: my question is different i want to know that should i use ejs template or jade ? if no then what will be form action in html file ?